# How to avoid repetitions of columns in MySQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

[image: 4 tables Relationship]

[image]

i am retrieving the result from above 4 table using following query

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(CASE when c.Training_Id=1 then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN enrolled_students es 
ON  c.Course_Id = es.Course_Id
) STEM,

(SELECT SUM(CASE when c.Training_Id=2 then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN enrolled_students es ON  c.Course_Id = es.Course_Id
)   MA,  
c.* FROM campus c;
```

The problem with this query is, two(2) students are in STEM and one(1) Student in MA against Campus_Id 3, but its repeating records against all campuses. i want if campus has no students than there should be '0' Zero.

Comment: Proper create and insert statements, and a corresponding desired result thanks. Preferably, an SQLfiddle too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your subselects by `Campus_Id`. But first you have to use distinct table aliases. Change your last line to `ca.* FROM campus ca`. Then you can use a where clause in your subselects (`WHERE c.Campus_Id = ca.Campus_Id`).

```sql
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(CASE when c.Training_Id=1 then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN enrolled_students es 
ON  c.Course_Id = es.Course_Id
WHERE c.Campus_Id = ca.Campus_Id -- line added
) STEM,

(SELECT SUM(CASE when c.Training_Id=2 then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN enrolled_students es ON  c.Course_Id = es.Course_Id
WHERE c.Campus_Id = ca.Campus_Id -- line added
)   MA,  
ca.* FROM campus ca; -- line changed
```

This should solve your problem.

To improve the performance you can also filter your subselects by `Training_Id`. In the first subselect you only need the rows with `Training_Id=1`. So you can change your where clause to:

```sql
WHERE c.Campus_Id = ca.Campus_Id
  AND c.Training_Id = 1
```

Doing that you can also use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`. So your subselect would look like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN enrolled_students es ON c.Course_Id = es.Course_Id
WHERE c.Campus_Id = ca.Campus_Id AND c.Training_Id = 1
```

To prevent code duplication (your subselects are almost equal) you can join all needed tables and group by `Campus_Id`:

```sql
select
    COUNT(co.Training_Id=1 OR NULL) STEM,
    COUNT(co.Training_Id=2 OR NULL) MA,
    ca.Campus_Id
from campus ca
left join courses co on co.Campus_Id = ca.Campus_Id
left join enrolled_students es on es.Course_Id = co.Course_Id
where co.Training_Id in (1, 2)
group by ca.Campus_Id
```